# Rust Refs & Derefs

Tags: rust, reference, dereference

Would like to check if my understandings are correct:

case 1

```
fn main() {

    let x = 5;
    let y = x;

    assert_eq!(5, y);        
    println!("y = {}", y);
}
```

Q1) {assert_eq!(5, &y)} would fail ("no implementation for `{integer} == &{integer}`"). I think y clones the value of 5 in the stack? Because it is primitive?

case 2

```
fn main() {

    let x = 5;
    let y = &x;

    assert_eq!(5, *y);         
    println!("y = {}", y);
}
```

Q2) this is how I infer case 1, as seemingly this is how to force a ref instead of cloning in case of primitives? In this case y contains the address (or stack position) of x?

Q3) if x is a string allocated from heap, as in:

```
fn main() {

    let x = String::from("Five");
    let y = &x;

    assert_eq!("Five", y);         
    println!("y = {}", y);
}
```

{assert_eq!(5, y)} would suffice (vs *y) only because of implicit deref of compiler?

case 3

```
fn main() {

    let x = 5;
    let &y = &x;

    assert_eq!(5, y);          
    println!("y = {}", y);
}
```

Similar to case 1 but not a clone? What is y?  A ref to ref x?  Compiler says y is an integer (presumably '5'), and this because the compiler will auto resolve daisy-chained refs I believe?

case 4

```
fn main() {

    let x = 5;
    let &y = &x;
    let &z = &&x;

    assert_eq!(5, *z); 
    println!("y = {}", z);
}
```

The above works but not with {assert_eq!(5, z)} - this is not the same as daisy-chaining refs?

Comment: The `*` operator calls [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) which can actually go through several levels of reference in one shot.

Comment: *"if x is a string allocated from heap"* - I don't know what this means, why is "string" part of it? And do you mean allocated on the heap via `Box`? Or do you mean replace `x` with a `String`? Then what is `y`? Its not clear.

Comment: Added proper code sample to Q3 for clarifying what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1) {assert_eq!(5, &y)} would fail ("no implementation for {integer} == &{integer}"). I think y clones the value of 5 in the stack? Because it is primitive?

It's because it is [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html), hence values are, well, copied. Rather than moved.

> Q2) this is how I infer case 1, as seemingly this is how to force a ref instead of cloning in case of primitives?

You're still forcing a copy when you dereference `y`.

> In this case y contains the address (or stack position) of x?

Sure.

> Q3) if x is a string allocated from heap, {assert_eq!(5, y)} would suffice (vs *y) only because of implicit deref of compiler?

Well first it'd never work because the types can not match, `5` is never a valid string, or reference to string, or anything even remotely close to a string.

Second, implicit dereference only comes into play when calling methods, although as tadman notes a single `*` might go through multiple levels of dereference.

> (case 4) Similar to case 1 but not a clone? What is y? A ref to ref x? Compiler says y is an integer (presumably '5'), and this because the compiler will auto resolve daisy-chained refs I believe?

There's no daisy chain. [The left hand of `let` is a pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html#let-statements). By design, patterns try to reverse an existing operation using the same syntax.

`let &y = ...` is a dereference of the value, as if you'd written `let y = *...` (except more limited, it only works with references). Not to be confused with `ref` (which is essentially the reverse of `*`).

Therefore this does the exact same thing as case 1 in a roundabout way, including the copy. `y` is an integer, of the same type as `x`.

> (case 5) The above works but not with {assert_eq!(5, z)} - this is not the same as daisy-chaining refs?

If you apply the rule above you can see that:

- `x: i32`
- `y: i32` because `let &y = &x;` is a complicated way of writing `let y = x;` aka a copy
- `z: &i32` because in the same way `let &z = &&x;` is a complicated way of writing `let z = &x`, aka a reference to `x`

Which is why you have to dereference `z` for the type to match with `5`.

Comment: Thanks @Masklinn, the link to chapter 17 is very useful.  I was only up to chapter 15...

Added code example of Q3, hopefully that clarifies my question.

Also, do you mind elaborating on "you're still forcing a copy when you dereference y."?

Comment: Q3: this works because [`str` implements `PartialEq` for a bunch of other types, including `String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#impl-PartialEq%3C%26%27a%20str%3E-for-String). So basically the standard library directly provides support for `String == &str` and `&str == String`, and that's why it works.

Comment: For the second part, if you have an `&T`, then dereference (the `*` operator) will give you a `T`, but lifetime bound to the original reference. There are three possible cases then: if the value is immediately re-borrowed, either explicitly, or because you're calling a borrowing method call, then that works, the "creation" of the actual value is skipped. The second case is a "normal" (move) type, in that case you get an error because you're trying to move out of a borrow, which is not allowed. The third case is a `Copy` type, where the value can just be copied out and it works fine.

Comment: This applies to pointers in general: references, collections, refcounted pointers, lock guards, ... the one exception is `Box` which you can move out of, so `*v` where `v: Box<T>` can destroy the box and give you the `T` itself, however that's unique to `Box`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=69c9dc888ebb8417c9d86f7fdd18ffaf